# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length') for vertices of three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

So I'm converting an html project to a laravel/vue project.
The html file had a three.min.js file which I can not figure out the version of. And some custom script files.

I've imported all of them for my vue component.
I ran into different errors for the three.min.js file, so I npm installed version r69 of three.js becauseI read in recent versions, the geometry had changed.
One of the custom files, test.js is using three.js.
And I am running into the following error in my console.log

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
at test.js?t=1674045010699:37:39

test.js file code:

```
import * as THREE from "three";

// import ('../../assets/js/three.min.js')
// import "../js/anime.js"
// import "../js/three.js"

var canvas = document.querySelector("#scene");
var width = canvas.offsetWidth,
    height = canvas.offsetHeight;
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    canvas: canvas,
    antialias: true,
});
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio > 1 ? 2 : 1);
renderer.setSize(width, height);
renderer.setClearColor(0x161d31);
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(100, width / height, 0.1, 10000);
camera.position.set(120, 0, 300);
var light = new THREE.HemisphereLight(0xffffff, 0x0c056d, 0.6);
scene.add(light);
var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0x590d82, 0.5);
light.position.set(100, 300, 400);
scene.add(light);
var light2 = light.clone();
light2.position.set(-100, 300, 400);
scene.add(light2);

var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    emissive: 0x23f660,
    emissiveIntensity: 0.4,
    shininess: 0,
});

var geometry = new THREE.IcosahedronGeometry(120, 4);

for (var i = 0; i < geometry.vertices.length; i++) {
    var vector = geometry.vertices[i];
    vector._o = vector.clone();
}

var shape = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(shape);

function updateVertices(a) {
    for (var i = 0; i < geometry.vertices.length; i++) {
        var vector = geometry.vertices[i];
        vector.copy(vector._o);
        var perlin = noise.simplex3(
            vector.x * 0.006 + a * 0.0002,
            vector.y * 0.006 + a * 0.0003,
            vector.z * 0.006
        );
        var ratio = perlin * 0.4 * (mouse.y + 0.3) + 0.9;
        vector.multiplyScalar(ratio);
    }
    geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
}

function render(a) {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    updateVertices(a);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

function onResize() {
    canvas.style.width = "";
    canvas.style.height = "";
    width = canvas.offsetWidth;
    height = canvas.offsetHeight;
    camera.aspect = width / height;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize(width, height);
}

var mouse = new THREE.Vector2(0.8, 0.5);
function onMouseMove(e) {
    TweenMax.to(mouse, 0.8, {
        y: e.clientY / height,
        x: e.clientX / width,
        ease: Power1.easeOut,
    });
}

requestAnimationFrame(render);
window.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
var resizeTm;
window.addEventListener("resize", function () {
    resizeTm = clearTimeout(resizeTm);
    resizeTm = setTimeout(onResize, 200);
});
```

I don't know anything about three.js, my main task here is to convert the entire project into vue/laravel so I have other things to worry about.
Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: What is unclear about an error message such as _“Cannot read property `length` of `undefined`”_? You can’t read properties of `undefined`, but that’s what happens at `geometry.vertices.length` because `geometry.vertices` is `undefined`; it’s trying to get `length` off of `undefined` — not possible. If you don’t know why `geometry.vertices` is `undefined`, use the debugger or look at intermediate values: `console.log(geometry);`. In Firefox, you can click the “[\[Learn more\]](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Unexpected_type)” link next to the error message.

Comment: @SebastianSimon I didn't say for once that error message in unclear. I said I didn't know anything about three.js I read in some threads that geometry.vertices is deprecated. From the three.min.js file that came with the html theme doesn't say its version number. And I can't import minified files without other errors hence I had to npm install the latest/random versions which is I guess causing this. The reason I posted here thinking others might've encountered this and know what I could replace this part with

Comment: `geometry.vertices.length` does not exist on your version of three.js. Version `r69` is very outdated ([released in 2014](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/releases/tag/r69)), so you're gonna have a hard time finding help and documentation on such an old release. I recommend you update your version of Three.js.

Comment: It does not exist in later versions, from r123 its gone totally, which is why Im using such an old one. Interesting the exact same thing works in this codepen with r83, but not when I do it my vue component. Codepen: https://codepen.io/Sidechain_Studio/pen/VxdgMX?editors=1111

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've migrated the code to a more recent version of `three.js`. The code now uses `BufferGeometry` (the new geometry format) so the original runtime error is gone.

```js
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize);

const scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.background = new THREE.Color(0x161d31);

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(100, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 10000);
camera.position.set(120, 0, 300);

const light = new THREE.HemisphereLight(0xffffff, 0x0c056d, 0.6);
scene.add(light);

const light1 = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0x590d82, 0.5);
light1.position.set(100, 300, 400);
scene.add(light1);

const light2 = light1.clone();
light2.position.set(-100, 300, 400);
scene.add(light2);

const material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
  emissive: 0x23f660,
  emissiveIntensity: 0.4
});

const geometry = new THREE.IcosahedronGeometry(120, 12);
const positionAttributeBase = geometry.getAttribute( 'position' ).clone();

const shape = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(shape);

const simplex = new THREE.SimplexNoise();
const vector = new THREE.Vector3();

function updateVertices(time) {

  const positionAttribute = geometry.getAttribute('position');

  for (let i = 0; i < positionAttributeBase.count; i++) {
    vector.fromBufferAttribute(positionAttributeBase, i);
    const noise = simplex.noise3d(
      vector.x * 0.006 + time * 0.0002,
      vector.y * 0.006 + time * 0.0003,
      vector.z * 0.006
    );
    const ratio = noise * 0.4 + 0.9;
    vector.multiplyScalar(ratio);
    positionAttribute.setXYZ(i, vector.x, vector.y, vector.z)
  }
  positionAttribute.needsUpdate = true;
}

function animate(time=0) {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  updateVertices(time);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

function onWindowResize() {

  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

}

animate();
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.147/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.147/examples/js/math/SimplexNoise.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hello @Mugen87, I appreciate your help, I tried your code. Unfortunately, I'm getting a new error: " Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: THREE.SimplexNoise is not a constructor". 
I'm npm installed latest version of SimplexNoise and r147 of Three.js
I'm importing them as " import * as THREE from "three";
import {} from 'simplex-noise';" inside my test.js file. Do you know what could be the issue? Thanks

Comment: If you import `SimplexNoise` via ES6 import syntax, you don't need the `THREE` namespace when creating the noise instance. Besides, the import should look like so: `import { SimplexNoise } from 'three/addons/math/SimplexNoise.js';`

Comment: Hello, thank you for replying. I npm installed both, and after your comment imported as such " import {SimplexNoise} from "three/examples/js/math/SimplexNoise"" because that's where I could find it. But I get a new error: Missing "./examples/js/math/SimplexNoise" export in "three" package

Comment: It should be `examples/jsm`. Not `examples/js`.

Comment: Hello, thank you for replying.Alright so now I imported "import {SimplexNoise} from "three/examples/jsm/math/SimplexNoise" still I'm receiving the same TypeError unfortunately. Do you know what could be the issue? Sorry for disturbing

Comment: Resolved!! Thank you so much!! All I had to do is remove the Three from new Three.simplexnoise